# Can HIV be automatically cured by waiting until CD4 T cells count drop to 0?

Tags: hiv

As I know, HIV needs host cell, CD4 T cell to repicate itself, and at late stage of AIDS, count of this cell in patient will drop to 0, my question is, if we can provide a sterilised environment for AIDS patients at late stage, will HIV be cured because CD4 T cells drop to 0 and hence no host cell for HIV to replicate itself?

Comment: Short answer: no. You might be able to put the patient into a sterile environment, but they will always carry into that environment every normal and - worse - opportunistic - organism they have into the room with them. So, no. They will die from bacteria or reactivated viruses or fungi or parasites (e.g. toxoplasmosis) that live in the body.

Comment: HIV can hide in many kinds of immune cells, like macrophages.